Concatenate Columns Using VBA
I have this code to concatenate data from different columns. But its not giving any results, while I have no idea what's the problem.
Things I want to do are:

Concatenate from Column AJ to AP with delimiter, and
Paste the value to Column PN in each row

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    
    Dim srcRng As Range, RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
        Set srcRng = ws1.Range("A2:AO152")
        RowCnt = srcRng.Rows.Count
        ColCnt = srcRng.Columns.Count
    
    With ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt)
        .Value = srcRng.Value
        With .Columns(320)  ' Col PN
            ' Apply formula to concate Col AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-394] & "","" & RC[-393] & RC[-392] & "","" & RC[-391] & "","" & RC[-390] & "","" & RC[-389] & ""-"" & RC[-388]"
            ' Convert formulas to values
            .Formula = .Value
        End With
    End With


Concat Consecutive Columns

Sub ConcatColumns()

    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    Const CONCAT_COLUMNS As String = "AJ:AP"
    Const RETURN_COLUMN As String = "PN"
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Import")
   
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws1.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        rCount = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.EntireRow.Columns(CONCAT_COLUMNS).Value
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For c = 2 To UBound(Data, 2)
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Data(r, 1) = Data(r, 1) & DELIMITER & Data(r, c)
        Next r
    Next c
    
    rg.EntireRow.Columns(RETURN_COLUMN).Value = Data
            
End Sub



Col PN should be .Columns("PN") or .Columns(430). The former notation is easier to follow.

Get the Col index with


Debug.Print Range("PN1").Column


Yous code missing Offset(1) in the With clause. Otherwise, the last row of the source table will be overwritten by .Value = srcRng.Value.

Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    Dim srcRng As Range, RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Const START_ROW = 2
    Set lastCell = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set srcRng = ws1.Range(lastCell, "A" & START_ROW)
    ' With srcRng.EntireRow.Columns("PN")  ' or .Columns(430), Col PN
    With srcRng.Offset(,Range("PN1").Column-1)
        ' Apply formula to concate Col AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-394] & "","" & RC[-393] & RC[-392] & "","" & RC[-391] & "","" & RC[-390] & "","" & RC[-389] & ""-"" & RC[-388]"
        ' Convert formulas to values
        .Formula = .Value
    End With
End Sub


ohh i get it. I have more issue. Instead of writing "A2:O152" i want the code to search for the last row. How could i make it possible?

Plus why does the code makes the concatenate values goes to the last row empty in column PN. It should be written in the same row but its not.
